# How to to arrange a loop in order to loop over columns and then do something

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I'm a complete newbie to python, and I'm currently trying to work on a problem that allows me to take the average of each column except the number of columns is unknown.

I figured how to do it if I knew how many columns it is and to do each calculation separate. I'm supposed to do it by creating an empty list and looping the columns back into it.

```
import numpy as np
#average of all data not including NAN
def average (dataset):
    return np.mean (dataset [np.isfinite (dataset)])
#this is how I did it by each column separate
dataset = np.genfromtxt("some file")
print (average(dataset [:,0]))    
print (average(dataset [:,1]))
#what I'm trying to do with a loop
def avg (dataset): 
    for column in dataset:
        lst = []
        column = #i'm not sure how to define how many columns I have
        Avg = average (column)
        return Avg
```

Comment: Do you mean taking the mean about a specified axis?

Comment: I'm just trying to the average of each column of a numpy array, but the number of columns differs from each dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can use the numpy.mean() function:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

with:

`np.mean(my_data, axis=0)`

The axis indicates whether you are taking the average along columns or rows (axis = 0 means you take the average of each column, what you are trying to do). The output will be a vector whose length is the same as the number of columns (or rows) along which you took the average, and each element is the average of the corresponding column (or row). You do not need to know the shape of the matrix in advance to do this.

You CAN do this using a for loop, but it's not a good idea -- looping over matrices in numpy is slow, whereas using vectorized operations like np.mean() is very very fast. So in general when using numpy one tries to use those types of built-in operations instead of looping over everything at least if possible.

Also -- if you want the number of columns in your matrix -- it's

`my_matrix.shape[1]`

returns number of columns;

`my_matrix.shape[0]` is number of rows.

Comment: I have some random data with 2 columns of data, but when I use np.mean, I get one answer back for an average when I want an average for each column

Comment: @user Don't forget to pass the `axis` parameter. `np.mean(dataset)` will give you the mean for all the values in the array. `np.mean(data, axis=0)` will give you an array of means across rows (2 in your case) and `np.mean(dataset, axis=1)` will give you an array of means across columns (100 in your case).